# redirect output to feed as an input to command line?

Tags: java, perl, bash, syntax, redirect

I want to run the following code inside a bash script:

```
java -jar VarScan.v2.2.jar somatic < samtools view -b -u -q 1 $n_b \
| samtools pileup -f $r - < samtools view -b -u -q 1 $t_b \
| samtools pileup -f $r - output
```

where $n_b and $t_b are files.

The java somatic function takes 2 paramters. so

```
samtools view -b -u -q 1 $n_b | samtools pileup -f $r
```

is one of the parameters and

```
samtools view -b -u -q 1 $t_b | samtools pileup -f $r
```

is the other paramter. Both the parameters are executable themselves.

So what i want is

```
samtools view -b -u -q 1 $n_b | samtools pileup -f $r -
```

execute first then

```
samtools view -b -u -q 1 $t_b | samtools pileup -f $r
```

and the output becomes the input for the somatic.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I do not know about somatic VarScan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is found at:

https://gist.github.com/1022747

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] I think I understand your question now, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Let's start with the simplest possible example that has the same number of distinct command lines as your example. Imagine you have three programs, 'somatic', 'samtools1' and 'samtools2'. somatic takes two arguments, and samtools1 and samtools2 take none.

Let's imagine further that when samtools1 is run, it results in a single word 'output1'. And similarly, let's imagine that when samtools2 is run, it results in a single word 'output2'. You would then like to run the command

```
somatic output1 output2
```

as the command line.

The way to achieve this is

```
somatic `samtools1` `samtools2`
```

There is no redirection involved.

Or in gory detail, using your original example, something like

```
java -jar VarScan.v2.2.jar somatic `samtools view -b -u -q 1 $n_b | samtools pileup -f $r -` `samtools view -b -u -q 1 $t_b | samtools pileup -f $r - output`
```

Although there may be some interplay between ` and | that requires some brackets or quoting. I haven't actually tried to run this.

[Old Stuff Left for auditing]

Your question is not completely clear to me: are you clear in your mind whether you want to redirect output or to formulate a command line? I suspect you mean the latter, since you talk about two parameters, and there is only 1 standard input.

If you want to formulate a command line parameter from the output of a command, the bash syntax to use is backquotes '`'

For example, to run a command 'mycommand' that expects a date as its command line argumemt, you could use

```
mycommand `date`
```

Which will run the date command, and use the output of the command as the first argument to mycommand.

Comment: Thank you for responding...ok i tried to rephrase my question.Can you understand now..

Comment: Not sure, does that help more?

Comment: ok..this is the link from the software...http://varscan.sourceforge.net/somatic-calling.html#somatic-input

Comment: Thanks...Burleigh Bear..! i will try your suggestion. Really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer because I lacked understanding the question:

<strike>I would use</strike>

(samtools view -b -u -q 1 $n_b | samtools pileup -f $r -; \
     samtools view -b -u -q 1 $t_b | samtools pileup -f $r -) \
    | java -jar VarScan.v2.2.jar somatic output

Comment: $n_p and $t_p are executable commands.so in the end we get a one command:

Comment: java -jar VarScan.v2.2.jar somatic <\(samtools view -b -u -q 1 $n_b | samtools pileup -f $r -\) <\(samtools view -b -u -q 1 $t_b | samtools pileup -f $r -\) output

Comment: but $n_p and $t_p are input parameters for the somatic function of the Varscan:

Comment: Hey Peter...thanks for your comment..really appreciate it. I have updated my question so it is more clear now...thansk